# Message set for GNSS/INS ROS Driver (node) - Standardized

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to develop a driver (node) for a commercial GNSS/INS unit. For that I think it is important NOT to use custom message sets, but rather standardized ones.

I have found the following:

- `sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.msg` for position (and GPS status)
- `nav_msgs/Odometry.msg` which gives position (again) and twist (velocities)
- `sensor_msgs/Imu.msg` IMU data
- `GPSFix.msg` and `GPSStatus.msg` from [gps_common](http://wiki.ros.org/gps_common), which has a lot of types

What would be the best design approach?

Can any one with experience or not point me to the right direction? I think this would be important for people doing similar work as mine! Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

After some digging, here also some extra pointers:

- Check [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) and [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html)
- Check [ROS Robot Localization package](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html).
- I wouldn't recommend using [gps_common](http://wiki.ros.org/gps_common).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272359/message-set-for-gnss/ins-ros-driver-(node)---standardized/) by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2017-10-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm sure one of the regulars can give you a better answer than me, but here's my 2 cents worth based on my experience working with GPS/navigation/localization.

- `sensor_msgs/NavSatFix` Most of the GPS drivers/devices I've used with ROS publish a `sensor_msgs/NavSatFix` message. And certainly several localization modules like `navsat_transform` in the [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package expect GPS data of that message type.
- `sensor_msgs/Imu` seems to be the standard and expected ROS message for IMU data.
- `nav_msgs/Odometry` is an odometry data type, so the data has to be relative to some reference frame. Often localization packages will publish this message with data relative to a reference frame (commonly called `odom` or `map`) that is created when the localization package is launched.

I don't know much about the [gps_common](http://wiki.ros.org/gps_common) package sorry as I haven't used it. I have used the [nmea_navsat_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/nmea_navsat_driver) package though. You could look at both for inspiration.

As for what you want your driver to publish, I'm not sure what best practice is. A lot of ROS localization/mapping packages will expect an `nav_msgs/Imu` message at the least, so that's almost certainly data you'll want to provide whether it's raw or combined GNSS/INS. As a potential user I would want to see:

1. A `sensor_msgs/Imu` and `sensor_msgs/NavSatFix` message containing raw, uncombined data. Possibly also duplicates of these messages, but with combined data from your aided INS engine.
2. Combined GNSS/INS data in a `nav_msgs/Odometry` message relative to either the 0,0 location of the UTM grid or to a ROS reference frame created when the drivers are launched.

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) with karma: 2327 on 2017-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-06**:
Shouldn't that be `sensor_msgs/Imu`?

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-10-06**:
Oops, you're right! Thanks for correcting me.